# Create an organization assets library inside the root site, is there any restrictions

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration

I want to Create an organization assets library inside the root site, is there any restrictions? i will follow the steps mentioned on this link @ https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/organization-assets-library ??

Comment: What type of restrictions you want to know? if you create a assets library then CDN will be enabled, all assets libraries should be on same site collection and you have to configure the permissions as per your need.

Comment: @GaneshSanap so it is fine to use the root site collection which is of type classic team site?

Comment: Site can be any type of site, such as a communication site, an Office 365 group-connected team site, or a modern team site that isn't connected to an Office 365 group.

Comment: @GaneshSanap thanks for the info, so can it be a classic team site?

Comment: Yes, you can use classic team site as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any restrictions on using organization assets library inside the root site.

However, you should note below points related to using organization assets library:

1. All organization assets libraries must be on the same site.
2. You can create up to 30 organization asset libraries for a single organization.
3. Adding an organization assets library will enable a content delivery network (CDN) for your organization.
4. Organization assets libraries can be created in any type of site, including:

   - Communication site
   - Microsoft 365 group-connected team site
   - Modern team site that isn't connected to an Microsoft 365 group
   - Classic team site

Comment: Hi @John John, does this answers you question?